# Kotlin/Native: How to perform blocking calls asynchronously?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

As of now, Kotlin/Native is single-threaded. Therefore, the following code will become blocked by `sleep`:

```kotlin
coroutineScope {
  launch { plaform.posix._sleep(100000) }
  launch { println("Hello")             }
}
```

However, it has a novel concurrency mechanism called [Workers](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-concurrency.html). Yet, even with worker the main thread is going to be blocked by long-running posix call:

```kotlin
coroutineScope {
  launch { Worker.start().execute(TransferMode.SAFE, { }, { plaform.posix._sleep(100000) }).consume{ } }
  launch { println("Hello") }
}
```

Both of the snippets above will never print `Hello`.

What is the correct way to perform a series of expensive blocking calls asynchronously?

Answer (score 4):

There is a multithreaded version of kotlin coroutines for K/N, which lives on a separate branch currently: [native-mt](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/native-mt).

You could use [Dispatchers.Default](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core/native/src/Dispatchers.kt#L10) to offload tasks to the background thread

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem is that I used the `consume` method, which blocks the main thread.

Instead, you need to execute the worker, and then check manually whether it finished:

```kotlin
val job = Worker.start().execute(TransferMode.SAFE, { }) { plaform.posix._sleep(100000) }
...
if (job.state == FutureState.Computed)
   job.result
```